# Failed griddle seasoning

Tags: seasoning, griddle

I have a viking stove in a house I recently purchased.  It has a griddle, I cleaned it with a grill stone using oil while it was cold (the griddle).  It cleaned well.  Next, I used flax oil to season it. I have never done this before nor have I owned a griddle.  I watched several youtube videos.  I turned the griddle on to medium heat spread flax oil with paper towel on it.  I allowed it to burn for about 10 min, the smoking stopped, allowed it to cool, I then did it again, this time I got distracted and the heat was left on for about an hour, when I checked it the edges looked black (although scattered and uneven, nothing like what I see on the youtube videos).  The middle area (scattered) had an appearance that I burned the oil.  Some areas look like a thick and hard.  It looks nothing like what I saw on the videos.  How do I fix this

Comment: Not sure if this is an exact duplicate (I can't find a question that references this sort of issue during initial seasoning) but it sounds similar to the type of seasoning issues described here and elsewhere: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64102/my-cast-iron-has-become-flaky-did-i-damage-it?rq=1 In short, it sounds like possibly too much oil and too much heat, and you'll be best off stripping it and starting again. Use the oven next time; it maintains a set temperature so it won't cause too much harm if you get sidetracked.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, this answer collects some of the better instructions I've seen lately for seasoning cast iron: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/90278/25059

Comment: When you put on the oil, was it before or after the griddle had a chance to warm up?  You want it warm, so the oil thins out so you're getting a really, really thin layer.  And if it fits in the oven, use that ... you'll get a consistent temperature the whole way across the griddle

Answer (score 2):

WWGD? (What would Grandma do). To avoid uneven seasoning, best to wash it all off as much as you can and start the seasoning process all over again.